# How to find definite integral of the product of two functions that are the same?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

It's hard to explain, but a specific example would be:

$$\pi\int_{0}^6 (g'(x))^2dx$$

Here, I was not given a specific function of g'(x), only a graph of g', where g'(6) = 0 and g'(0) = 4, and an initial value of g(6) = 11 and g(0) = -7.

I tried inverse power rule where I simplified it to $\frac1 3 (g(x))^3$. Doesn't work since I neglected Chain Rule.
I tried U-substitution but could not find a good "u". And finally integration by parts where I somehow ended up where I started, still unsolved.

Can someone lead me in the direction for me to start, so I can finally figure this out? It's been bothering me all day.

Comment: Well, $\int f(x)^2 dx$ doesn't have a known general form, so finding an antiderivative is not the answer. (Even if $f$ is the derivative of some function.) Notably, your integral seems to be the volume of the solid generated by rotating $g'$ around the $x$-axis, and I imagine the initial values for $g,g'$ are meant to play into this somewhat, but I can't figure out how... I assume this geometric interpretation is important though, however it's implemented.

Comment: I'm not sure this problem can be solved given the information. However, an observation; note that if this problem does depend on the endpoints of $g$, then it can only depend on their difference. Consider for example $f(x)=\sin x$ and $g(x)=\sin x+ 2$. Then $f'(x)=\cos x = g'(x)$, so they give the same value under that integral, however $g(x)>f(x)$ for all $x$.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer You're right in saying that it is the volume of a solid generated when rotating a rectangle of height g'(x) and a width/base of dx around the x-axis.

Comment: @jl00 This answer is for both of you guys, I seem to have made a typo in my initial post in that I was actually given the graph of **g'** instead of the graph of g. My knowledge on finding area under the curve of a graph that's squared is limited though.